# Círculo de duplicatas

Tags: bug, status-intencional, perguntas-duplicadas

Ao "andar" pela fila de análise eu encontrei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110531/20615), que chamaremos de A. A mesma possui 4 votos para fechar como duplicata [desta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110535/namespace-facebook-n%C3%A3o-funciona-jsf) que iremos chamar de B. Porém, a pergunta B já está fechada como duplicata de A, entrando assim em um loop, por assim dizer.
Ao me deparar com a pergunta A na fila, eu votei para fechar (sem perceber esse loop) e recebi o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente para ser uma verificação do sistema justamente para essas ocasiões. Minha dúvida é: **Como ele permitiu os outros 4 votos para fechar?**

Foi alguma funcionalidade implementada após os votos ou é um BUG do site?

Comment: Ou o sistema não foi com tua cara/nick/avatar, hehehe

Comment: @Earendul Magoou... Vou processar ele por danos morais. kkkk

Comment: Vai ver ele só verifica no último voto. Nem todos os outros 4 votos pra fechar podem ser pelo mesmo motivo ou apontando para a mesma duplicata.

Comment: @bfavaretto Apontando para a mesma eu não consigo saber, mas os quatro votos são como duplicatas. E eu não achei nenhuma outra parecida.

Comment: Eu quis dizer que parece que o sistema deixa para verificar só no último voto pois essas situações são possíveis. Por exemplo, se uma pergunto tiver 2 votos de duplicata e 3 de fora de escopo, ela será fechada como fora de escopo, sem nem verificar se existe a referência cíclica.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se a pergunta tiver 5 votos, independente dos motivos, ela é fechada?

Comment: É. Se forem 5 motivos de diferentes, acho que o "oficial" fica sendo o do último voto.

Comment: @bfavaretto Isso eu desconhecia. Mas, apesar disso é meio estranho aceitar esse "loop" na marcação.

Comment: Se você entrar no perfil dele vai notar a mania de duplicar proposital dele, eram "tantas" que o povo nem sabia qual fechar e acabou que a primeira já tinha votos mas não foi fechada e a segunda foi fechada primeiro. Ou seja é uma trava de segurança mesmo. O pior é a atitude dele mesmo.

Comment: Precisa ver se o fechamento da outra não aconteceu depois do quarto voto desta.

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista é totalmente normal ele verificar no final, pois antes de receber 5 votos ela continua sendo "uma pergunta nova". De tal forma que 4 votos não a definem ainda como "duplicada", "fora de escopo", etc.

Comment: @Bacco Isso eu não consigo e/ou não sei verificar. Apenas achei estranho esse comportamento.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Da forma que contextuou parece certo, mas olhando em um contexto geral, é meio estranho aceitar esse tipo de coisa. Imagine uma pergunta sua sendo marcada para fechar pois é duplicada de uma pergunta que veio depois? E como se não bastasse, a outra está fechada como duplicada da  sua, até eu fiquei confuso. Mas essa confusão que "acho estranho".

Comment: @Randrade de fato, é complicado, creio que isso não deveria acontecer, ao mesmo tempo, é bom, pois creia sinônimos levando possíveis leitores a ambas. Ainda reforço que é errado pois não seria possível responder ambas. Eu ja tinha sugerido as duplicadas virassem sinônimos, mas a ideia não foi pra frente.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Isso seria interessante. As vezes uma duplicada possui respostas tão boas, senão melhor, que a sua original.

Comment: @Randrade http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4514/perguntas-duplicadas-links-e-sinonimos